# Makefile linking to additional Project

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, include

I have a very simple error, so simple even that I can't find tutorials that cover such a basic step.
I have a project in eclipse, and I have to use a Makefile. It was build automatically, and looks like this:

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmassage-length=0 -std=c++0x
OBJS =      Trie.o Node.o main.o
LIBS = 
TARGET =    main
$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBS) $(LIBS)

all:    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Now my Problem is, that I also want to use a class from another project. Telling eclipse is easy, just check the box in "Project References" and I can include away. But as soon as I compile, this happens:

```
fatal error: otherProjectDir/GenericList.hpp: No such file or directory
```

So I guess the makefile needs to be told, too.

How? And is there an automatic way to let eclipse cover this?

Comment: Is that a generated file or a file that already exists in your other project? If it is a generated file then you need to tell make how to generate it. If it is a pre-existing file then you likely just need to update the CXXFLAGS variable with an appropriate `-I/path/to/otherProjectDir-Parent` argument.

Comment: Thank you. It is a generated file, but I could not find an option to link additional projects in the generation wizard, so now I edit it by hand. I will try your tip first thing in the morning.

Comment: It worked, but big part of the error I got, and why I could not get any other help to work was, that the the generic list contained, well, generic types. And I didn't properly take care of them, in ways I still don't really understand.